# Objective C MVC patterns - Settings Panel task delegation

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, view, singleton

By the suggestion of SO folk in a previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247406/objective-c-communicating-to-one-view-controller-that-another-has-changed)), I'm in the process of making my primary model object a singleton to share between a "main" view controller and a "settings" view controller. I think this setup will be great once it's complete, but I'm having an issue with laying it out in an MVC-friendly manner.

At the moment, my settings view currently initializes settings on viewDidLoad if none exist (via NSUserDefaults), lays out subviews depending on what buttons are selected (settings view holds all settings button outlets), updates a dictionary of button states when a button is pressed, saves those updated to the NSUserDefaults, updates the settings panel subviews, and sends the button settings to the singleton.

Meanwhile, my singleton converts the button settings to a dictionary of settings that the model object will understand & updates the model object with the information created so the main view controller can update its collection view with the new model objects.

I'm thinking laying out the subviews should be handled by the settings view. My question is am I having the settings view do too much of the problem? If so, should I have my singleton/model object update button states (therefore receiving an array of UIButtons from the view), and handle any NSUserDefaults-related tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's just me, but **this all sounds needlessly complex**.

If you've got a model that's going to handle settings information, why is your view dealing directly with NSUserDefaults? The job of a model is to manage information. If your "model" for your settings information is essentially like a dictionary, i.e. you've got a bunch of key/value pairs, then NSUserDefaults may be all the model you need, at least for the settings. Alternately, if you've gone to the trouble of creating a model that includes settings information, you should rely on the model to store and retrieve the information; don't go behind your model's back and access the information directly.

So, you can either do something like:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL foo = [defaults boolForKey:@"fooSetting"];
```

everywhere you need to access the setting for "foo", or you can do it once inside your model and have everything else in your app access the model when it needs that setting. Either one is okay, but don't do both.

**Aside:** I don't care what the folks responding to your other question said, you don't need to make your model a singleton just so you can access it from more than one view controller. I won't go into the whole singletons good vs. singletons bad argument here, but make sure you Google around a little and at least understand the issue.

Comment: As foolish as this sounds, I never really considered using NSUserDefaults as the exclusive container for settings information. I think there was something in the back of my mind saying that was "wrong" to do. In this situation, then, would it be advisable to simply have the view store button settings to NSUserDefaults, notify the model object that settings are ready, and have the model object update from NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I think you should choose between *either* leaving the settings data out of the model entirely and using NSUserDefaults directly from both view controllers, *or* making the model the sole source from which the controllers get their settings data. If you choose the latter, it's fine for the model to use NSUserDefaults behind the scenes, but that's not something the view controllers should be aware of.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your thorough explanations on both of my questions! I really appreciate it.